# How update an array, client side

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I tried to update an array in a collection by doing

```
Configs.update({_id:this.parent._id, "cles.cle":this.context.cle},
{$set: {"cles.$.alias": $(e.target).val()}});
```

but I got this error

> Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

How can I update data in an array, client side (minimongo) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I finally understand the basis of your question. It looks like Meteor is treating your subselection of the array element in your selection criteria as an attempt to circumvent the policy of only allowing individual record updates. This feels like a bug in Meteor.

A possible work around:

1. `var cles = Configs.findOne({_id:this.parent._id}).cles;`
2. Modify the `cles` array as desired
3. Update the *whole array* in place `Configs.update({_id:this.parent._id},{$set: {cles: cles});`

Feels clumsy. Another solution would be to create a server method to do this on the server side. This would be better if your array can be large.

Comment: Thanks, my array is not very large, i think it's a good solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `collection.update` on the client, the selector may point out docs by their `_id` field only. So you must do something like `collection.update({_id: "your id"}, <updates>})` (or by using the alternative `_id` selector: `collection.update("your id", <updates>})`).

Comment: ok, but how update , with only a _id and no index of the key of array where i must update my data? i miss something?
So perhaps i can do a find before? but nothing better?

Comment: Use the selector `{_id:this.parent._id}` instead of `{_id:this.parent._id,"cles.cle":this.context.cle}`.

Comment: thanks for your awnser but i want to update only this: "cles.cle":this.context.cle and not all key "cles.cle" ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.